# Make R matrix multiplication `%*%` dispatch on S3 objects

Tags: r, r-s4

I have an S3 class that has methods for most of the Math and Ops generics, and I would like for it to also work with `%*%`. Why doesn't this work?

```r
setOldClass("foo")

setMethod("%*%", signature(x = "foo", y = "foo"),
          function(x, y) { "foo-foo" })

x <- structure(list(), class = "foo")
y <- structure(list(), class = "foo")
x %*% y
#> Error in x %*% y: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

Comment: After an internal slack discussion with some knowledgeable colleagues, we concluded that this is not possible today (R 4.1 being the current release). At least one of the objects `x` or `y` must be an S4 object for dispatch to work.

Comment: Perhaps some judicious calls to `setOldClass` would make it work?